# Create a Macro that can: Match a value and then save the value and the value from the left then deleted everything else on the spread sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Create a Macro that can: Match a value and then save the value and the value from the left while deleting everything else on the spread sheet.
The issue is that the values can change position but the value to look for will remain the same.
I need to create a macro that can match a value, then save this value and the value to the left while deleting everything else. it may contain two or more different values:

ColumnA        ColumnB
    trees              leaves
    orange             fruit
    tomato             vegetable
    carrot             root
    onion              root
    apple              fruit

Then if values are fruit and root should contain:

apple fruit
orange  fruit
carrot root
onion  root
So it more items are added or if they are in different order I can still get the values needed (fruits and roots)

Comment: How are you going to tell the macro what it should look for?  And do you want everything on the sheet deleted or just hidden?

Comment: The value will already be pre-established, say for instance the given example says fruits and roots, so it will not change, the rest of the info needs to be deleted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want.
First it asks for the categories to match (defaulting for fruit and root).
Then it starts at the bottom of the list and moves up deleting each row that doesn't match.

```
Sub DeleteUnwantedItems()
    Values = Split(InputBox("Enter space separated categories:", , "fruit root"), " ")
    Row = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    For I = Row To 1 Step -1
        If UBound(Filter(Values, Cells(I, 2).Value)) = -1 Then Rows(I).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```